# Multiplication table with a little style

Tags: php, html, html-table

i have multiplication table and i want to modify it like follows - make first row and first column items bold and centered. If i understand correct for this i just have to use  tags. Still i can't figure out how to do this, that is what i tried..

```
<?php

$cols = 10;
$rows = 10;
?>
```

Lot of html text here...

```
<?php

        echo "<table border=\"1\">";





        for ($r =1; $r < $rows; $r++){



            echo('<tr>');



            for ($c = 1; $c < $cols; $c++)

            if ($r =1 or $c=1){
                echo('<th>'.$r*$c.'</th>');
            }


                echo( '<td>' .$c*$r.'</td>');
            echo('</tr>');
        }

        echo("</table>");


        ?>
```

I think i miss rather obvious solution how to do this.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused assignment and comparison operators. `=` is assignment operator. You need to use comparison operator (`==`) in `if` statement.

```
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($r = 1; $r <= $rows; $r++){
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($c = 1; $c <= $cols; $c++)
    if ($r == 1 || $c == 1)
        echo '<th>'. $r * $c. '</th>';
    else
        echo '<td>'. $r * $c. '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you! I just want to ask, could i replace || symbol with OR? For some reason i have no such symbols on keyboard, i can just copy and paste it.

Comment: You may use `OR` operator instead of `||`. In this case it doesnt matter

Answer (score 3):

Use the following CSS selector

```
table>tr:first-child>*, table>tr>td:first-child, table>tr>th:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center
 }
```